# Calculate days difference based on condition with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'category': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4],
              'date_start': ['2018-04-09','2018-05-03', '2018-06-22', '2018-09-21', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-24', '2018-02-24', '2018-03-31','2018-08-01', '2018-01-29'],
              'order_start': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]})
Out[67]: 
   category  date_start  order_start
0         1  2018-04-09            1
1         1  2018-05-03            2
2         1  2018-06-22            3
3         2  2018-09-21            1
4         2  2018-12-01            2
5         2  2018-12-24            3
6         3  2018-02-24            1
7         3  2018-03-31            2
8         3  2018-08-01            3
9         4  2018-01-29            1
```

As you can see, order_start depends of category and date_start. It is just the order of the start by category.

What would be the easiest / most efficient way to create a new column which contains the difference in days with the previous start ? I would like something which looks like this:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'category': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4],
              'date_start': ['2018-04-09','2018-05-03', '2018-06-22', '2018-09-21', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-24', '2018-02-24', '2018-03-31','2018-08-01', '2018-01-29'],
              'order_visit': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1],
              'diff_with_last_start': [0, 30, 24, 0, 23, 56, 0, 43, 54, 0]})
Out[68]: 
   category  date_start  order_start  diff_with_previous_start
0         1  2018-04-09            1                     0
1         1  2018-05-03            2                    25
2         1  2018-06-22            3                    49
3         2  2018-09-21            1                     0
4         2  2018-12-01            2                    70
5         2  2018-12-24            3                    56
6         3  2018-02-24            1                     0
7         3  2018-03-31            2                    43
8         3  2018-08-01            3                    54
9         4  2018-01-29            1                     0
```

Note 1: the difference is always 0 for the first start of each category.

Note 2: I didn't calculate the exact days difference in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `diff`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date_start']).groupby(df['category']).diff().dt.days
# or, if `date_start` is already datetime,
df.groupby('category')['date_start'].diff().dt.days 

0      NaN
1     24.0
2     50.0
3      NaN
4     71.0
5     23.0
6      NaN
7     35.0
8    123.0
9      NaN
Name: date_start, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['diff_with_previous_start'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'])
      .groupby(df['category'])
      .diff()
      .dt.days
      .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)
df

   category  date_start  order_start  diff_with_previous_start
0         1  2018-04-09            1                         0
1         1  2018-05-03            2                        24
2         1  2018-06-22            3                        50
3         2  2018-09-21            1                         0
4         2  2018-12-01            2                        71
5         2  2018-12-24            3                        23
6         3  2018-02-24            1                         0
7         3  2018-03-31            2                        35
8         3  2018-08-01            3                       123
9         4  2018-01-29            1                         0
```